# PHP Array sometimes returns just 'array'

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I wonder why I haven't found any solutions for this strange problem.
Sorry if I haven't looked right but I am very desperate and try to fix this as much as I can.

In a recursive function, I collect sql data and store them in an array.
However, when I use print_r for outputting the array values, I get strange values like this:

> a."parentMale" = '45273' OR a."parentFemale" = '44871' OR
>   a."parentMale" = '7625' OR a."parentFemale" = '7481' OR Array OR Array
>   OR Array OR Array OR a."parentMale" = ...

While my function looks like this:

```
    public function getSelfAndAncestorsShort($id) {
  $animalids = array();
  if ($id != "") 
  {
      $query = "SELECT a.\"parentMale\" AS sire, a.\"parentFemale\" AS dam
      FROM animals a
      WHERE a.id = ".$id;

      $res = pg_query($query);
      while ($row = pg_fetch_object($res)) 
      {
        if ($row->sire != "")
        $animalids[]  = "a.\"parentMale\" = '" .$row->sire ."'";
        if ($row->dam != "")
        $animalids[]  = "a.\"parentFemale\" = '" .$row->dam ."'";

        $animalids[] = $this->getSelfAndAncestorsShort($row->sire);
        $animalids[] = $this->getSelfAndAncestorsShort($row->dam);

        $animalids = implode (" OR ", $animalids);

      }

  }
  return $animalids;
}
```

I hope someone can help me because I have really no idea.

Comment: You get an error because in one of the results the array is returned and you are trying to process it as a string. You need to either fix the function and do a check on the data type

Comment: You are using implode() that change array to string and at last you are getting string only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function returns an array if `$id` is empty. Also, you do not check the return of your function before to add into your `$animalids` array :

```
public function getSelfAndAncestorsShort($id) {
  $animalids = array();
  if ($id != "")
  {
      $query = "SELECT a.\"parentMale\" AS sire, a.\"parentFemale\" AS dam
      FROM animals a
      WHERE a.id = ".$id;

      $res = pg_query($query);
      while ($row = pg_fetch_object($res))
      {
        if ($row->sire != "")
        $animalids[]  = "a.\"parentMale\" = '" .$row->sire ."'";
        if ($row->dam != "")
        $animalids[]  = "a.\"parentFemale\" = '" .$row->dam ."'";

        $val = $this->getSelfAndAncestorsShort($row->sire);
        if ($val) $animalids[] = $val; // Check here
        $val = $this->getSelfAndAncestorsShort($row->dam);
        if ($val) $animalids[] = $val; // Check here

      }

  }
  if (empty($animalids)) return "" ; // Check here
  return implode (" OR ", $animalids); // Only implode here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives me the expected result